# Pasar parametros desde una vista a un controlador usando href en Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Necesito ayuda para pasar un parámetro desde una vista a un controlador. El problema que tengo es que al enviar los datos me retorna un dato nulo y no el que estoy enviando, se supone que a través del "href:" debería de poder enviar la variable al controlador. Esta es mi vista:

```
@model List<Model.Cliente>
@{
ViewBag.title = "Cliente";
}
   <h2>Cleintes</h2>

    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="width:50px;">Id</th>
                <th style="width:100px;">RUT</th>
                <th>Razsoc</th>
                <th style="width:200px;"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var a in Model)
            {
            <tr>
                <td>@a.Id_clien<td>
                <td>@a.Rut</td>
                <td>@a.Nombre_clien</td>
                <td class="text-right">
                    <a class="btn btn-default btn-success" href="~/Menu/Ver/@a.Rut" title="Visualizar">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a class="btn btn-default" href="~/menu/crud/@a.Rut" title="Editar">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Y este es mi controlador:

```
using Model;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Sales.Controllers
{
public class MenuController : Controller
{
    private Cliente cliente = new Cliente();

    public ActionResult Inicio()
    {
        return View(cliente.Listar());
    }

    public ActionResult Ver(string rut)
    {
        return View(cliente.Obtener(rut));
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el `href` utiliza el helper `Url` y el método `Url.Action()`.

Este toma como parámetro el action, el controller (sin la palabra "Controller") y el routeValues el cual es un objeto con los parámetros que le pasaras al action. Tiene 9 sobrecargas más el método que puedes revisar, pero basicamente sería algo así:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Ver", "Menu", new { rut = a.Rut })" title="visualizar">
   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: Es exactamente lo que necesitaba. Muchas gracias me ha ayudado